# Can sets of functions form a measure space?

Tags: measure-theory, statistical-mechanics

For example, continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with nth derivative = 0.
Each function acts like a point in an $\mathbb{R}^n$ dimensional space with its Taylor expansion coefficients acting as coordinates:
$y=1 \rightarrow (1,0,0,...,0)$
$y=1+x+2x^{n-1} \rightarrow (1,1,0,...,2)$

Then the measure of the set of functions is simply its hypervolume in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or the measure of some lower dimensional shape it makes.

Does this scheme correctly outline the idea of a formal measure space? If so, is there a name for it or a more general method? The same basic idea should work for all kinds of vector spaces of functions: fourier series, spherical harmonics, bessel functions, etc.

I'm motivated by a physics problem where I'm trying to determine the entropy of a system which is easier to model with continuous mass rather than discrete particles. Intuitively I just need to quantify the number of states available to the system, and defining a measure for the set of possible distributions seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Not all smooth functions equal their Taylor series everywhere, so your outline is flawed. There are probability measures on function spaces, e.g. Brownian motion. But the way probabilities are assigned is far from  the intuition of "hypervolume". I am under the impression that a natural "hypervolume" doesn't exist in infinite dimensions.